# Expectation of square of Gaussian random variable.

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, gaussian

Let $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. For $\lambda <1/2$, why does this hold?

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\lambda\left(Z^2 - E[Z^2]\right)\right)\right]
 = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-2\lambda) - \lambda\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

In this case, $X=Z^2 \sim \chi^2_1$, so 
$$
f_X(x)
 = \frac{x^{-1/2}e^{-x/2}}{2^{1/2} \Gamma(1/2)}
 = \frac{x^{-1/2}e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$
and $\mathbb{E}[x] = 1$, so your LHS is
$$
\mathrm{LHS}
= \int_0^\infty e^{\lambda (x-1)} \frac{x^{-1/2}e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dx
= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
  \int_0^\infty x^{-1/2} e^{x(\lambda-1/2)}\ dx
$$
can you take it from here?

---

**UPDATE**

Let's substitute $a = 1/2 - \lambda,u = ax$ so $du = adx$ and since $\lambda < 1/2$, the $a>0$, so $u$ and $x$ have the same sign. Thus, as $x \to \infty$, we have $u \to \infty$ as well. Now
$$
\mathrm{LHS}
 = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
   \int_0^\infty (u/a)^{-1/2}e^{-u} \frac{du}{a}
$$
Could you express that as a Gamma($\Gamma$) function?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I could understand the derived part while the remaining derivation is still not solvable to me. I appreciate it if someone helps.